# Last element of column is divided between the two columns in sql query

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hello I am dumping a results from database in to 2 columns. My problem is that the last element on the first column is getting divided between the bottom and the of the first column and the top of the second column.

I am attaching visual example of it:

[image]

My CSS Code for the container is:

```
.datagrid {-moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
    font: normal 13px/120% 'Lato', sans-serif; background: #fff; overflow: hidden; 

    }
```

and the CSS for the elements is:

```
.documentlist { width:100%; 
                padding:10px; 
                display:table; 
                text-align:left; 
                margin: 0 0 1em; 
                background:#f5f7f9;
               }
```

This is the code of the SQL query

```
<div class="datagrid">   


$select = new Users;
$stmt = $select->selectdocumentlist($topic_id);
while( $row = $stmt->fetch()){          

{if($row['indicator'] == "1") 

{echo "        
<div class='documentlist'>
<div class='listinside_left'>
<img src='images/doc_icon.png'></div>
<div class='listinside_center'><a href='display_documents.php?id=24&topic=1&topic_id=16'>TEST 601</a></div>
<div class='folder_icon_delete'><a href='delete_documents.php?id=24'>
<img src='images/delete.png'></a>
</div>
</div>
;}}
```

Comment: I think it might be the problem of height, it would be like auto or something, try changing height for it.

Comment: It would be much easier and quicker if you create a demo to show us or give a link of your site